# Zabbix Trigger for SELinux (type=AVC) Errors

Tags: centos, selinux, zabbix

I would like to create a trigger in Zabbix to alert me anytime a `type=AVC` error appears in a CentOS 6 server's `/var/log/audit/audit.log` file.

I've already tried creating a basic log scrape.  E.g.:

```
log[/var/log/audit/audit.log,type=AVC,"UTF-8",100]
```

However, it does not work.  I believe this is due to the `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and it's parent folder using the following permissions:

```
drwxr-x---.  2 root root    4096 Apr 20 04:29 .
drwxr-xr-x. 13 root root    4096 Apr 14 12:07 ..
-rw-------.  1 root root 5948185 Apr 20 15:27 audit.log
-r--------.  1 root root 6291566 Apr 20 04:29 audit.log.1
-r--------.  1 root root 6291704 Apr 19 16:56 audit.log.2
-r--------.  1 root root 6291499 Apr 19 05:22 audit.log.3
-r--------.  1 root root 6291552 Apr 18 17:48 audit.log.4
```

I would prefer not to change the permissions for security reasons.

**Has anyone done log monitoring of `/var/log/audit/audit.log` using Zabbix?  And if so, how?**

Comment: Not used zabbix, but you can get AVCs emailed out to you by adding an email address to `/var/lib/setroubleshoot/email_alert_recipients`, this might help you by changing your MTA to execute a command on receipt of an email to a specified address.

Comment: The folder `/var/lib/setroubleshoot/` does not exist on my servers, am I supposed to create it?

Comment: Install the setroubleshoot-server package.

Comment: Thanks, we'll see what I can do to connect the MTA to Zabbix...  If it works I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also create a new logfile, on each host, that gets copies of the relevant messages you want to trigger. Then you just create a job to copy actionable messages, from other logs to the new single log.

I try to stay away from mail, as that adds other issues and can prevent your security alert from getting out.

Comment: Interesting idea...

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work, because you need to run zabbix agent as root, you must allow zabbix agent to access that file. After you can monitor file as usual.

Here is your template for SELinux:
https://github.com/GioMac/zabbix/blob/master/templates/Template_SELinux.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can use zabbix for [log file monitoring](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/log_items) to watch the `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for the expected regexp (`AVC` possibly) and set a trigger accordingly.